# LeetCode 231: Problem in finding whether a given number is Power of 2

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I want to find whether a given number is a [power of two](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-two/) in a mathematical way, *not* with a bitwise approach. Here is my code:

```
private static double logBaseTwo(final double x) {
    return Math.log(x) / Math.log(2);
}

private static double roundToNearestHundredThousandth(final double x) {
    return Math.round(x * 100000.0) / 100000.0;
}

private static boolean isInteger(final double x) {
    return (int)(Math.ceil(x)) == (int)(Math.floor(x));
}

public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(final int n) {
    return isInteger(roundToNearestHundredThousandth(logBaseTwo(n)));
}
```

It incorrectly returns `true` for certain numbers, such as `524287`. Why is that?

Comment: I hope that you realize that using a bit wise approach is a mathematical way. They way you're suggesting is overly complex and has trouble working on computers.

Comment: @ruakh It is wrong to edit the question such that it invalidates an answer. Please put the trinary  operator back.

Comment: @NomadMaker: The question was about why the code doesn't work. As rzwitserloot pointed out, the ternary operator didn't affect the behavior of the code; so it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @ruakh It confuses the understanding of the answer. It should have either been left in, or a comment put into the question stating that the original code (...) was replaced with this code (...).

Comment: @NomadMaker: I've now edited that answer to clarify what it's referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code fails because you may need more precision than you allow to capture the difference between the logs of BIG_NUMBER and BIG_NUMBER+1

The bitwise way is really best, but if you really want to use only "mathy" operations, then the best you can do is probably:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(final int n) {
   int exp = (int)Math.round(logBaseTwo(n));
   int test = (int)Math.round(Math.pow(2.0,exp));
   return test == n;
}
```

This solution does not require any super-fine precision, and will work fine for all positive ints.

Answer (score 1):

This is truly horrifyingly bad code, and I have no idea what you are trying to do. You seem to be trying to check if the `log` base `2` of `n` is an integer. Instead I would write a loop:

```
while (n>1) {
   m = (n/2) * 2
   if (n!=m){
       return false;
     }
   n /=2;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems more complicated than it should be. I don't get the `100000d` parts - seems to potentially cause problems when converting to ceiling.

This is the simple solution that works for all cases:

```java
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
    return Math.ceil(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2)) == Math.floor(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2));
}
```

Comment: +1. The rounding to the nearest hundred-thousandth is exactly the problem: log₂ 524287 ≈ 18.999997 is getting rounded to 19.0, which is an integer. So, in a sense, the OP's code is rounding 524287 to 524288, which is a power of two. (And, by the way, welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Comment: Actually, sorry, this answer is not correct: this code wrongly returns `false` for `536870912` (at least on my system), because the floating-point result is `29.000000000000004` instead of `29`.

Answer (score 1):

Originally I had a problem using `Math.log` in my computations.  I switched to `Math.log10` and the problem went away.  Although mathematically, any `logB` of base B should work, the nature of floating point math can be unpredictable.

Try this.

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
   return  n > 0 && Integer.highestOneBit(n) == Integer.lowestOneBit(n);
}
```

If you prefer to use logs you can do it this way.

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
   return n > 0 && (Math.log10(n)/Math.log10(2))%1 == 0;
}
```

Comment: It was my mistake and I am uncertain how I overlooked it.  Using Math.log did not eliminate the math error so I switched to Math.log10 and it worked.  This still bothers me because using the `log` of any base in both numerator and denominator should work.  But that's math and we're working with IEEE754 so even using the ceil and floor methods would not eliminate the tiny error from the computation.

Answer (score 0):

doubles and floats have, respectively, 64-bit and 32-bit precision. That means they can hold at the very most `18446744073709551616` unique numbers. That's a lot of numbers, but not an infinite amount of them. At some point (in fact, that point occurs about at 2^52), the 'gap' between any 2 numbers which are part of the 18446744073709551616 representable ones becomes larger than 1.000. Similar rules apply to small numbers. Math.log does `double` based math.

Secondarily, ints are similarly limited. They can hold up to 4294967296 different numbers. For ints it's much simpler: Ints can hold from -2147483648 up to 2147483647. If you try to add 1 to 2147483647, you get -2147483648 (it silently wraps around). It's quite possible you're running into that with trying to convert such a large number (your double times 10000d) to an int first.

Note that `? true : false` (as in the original version of the question) is literally completely useless. the thing to the left of the question mark must be a boolean, and booleans are already true or false, that's their nature.

See the other answers for simpler approaches to this problem. Although, of course, the simplest solution is to simply count bits in the number. If it's precisely 1 bit, it's a power of 2. If it's 0 bits, well, you tell me if you consider '0' a power of 2 :)